# Simplify a series expansion including product and multiplication

Tags: series-expansion

I have a following expression
$$
f=\Pi_{i=1}^n \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{t} +\frac{ (m+i)}{t^2} +\frac{ (m+i)^2}{t^3} + \cdots \right]
 $$
here $m,n,t$ are positive integers.

I want to obtain a series expansion for $f$ as $1/t,1/t^2,1/t^3,\cdots$ up to maybe $1/t^6$. A general expression for any order is not needed.

I used

```
f = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((1 + 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(t\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\((m + i)\), \(t^2\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(\((m + i)\)^2\), \(t^3\)])\)\)

Series[f, {t, Infinity, 3}, Assumptions -> Element[m, Integers]]
```

Mathematica 7.0 gives me a complicated expression including `Arg`, `Floor`, `Csc`, etc.

Is there any way to obtain simple expression? I can do low order by hand, but for high order, it is increasingly complicated..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Could you please add the actual code you evaluated before the `Series` function? `%` just refers to the prior evaluation, and we don't know exactly what you've done.

Comment: Thanks. It is just the expression for f. f = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((1 + 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(t\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\((m + i)\), \(t^2\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(\((m + i)\)^2\), \(t^3\)])\)\)

Comment: I have replaced % as f. In the input, only the expression up to $t^{-3}$ inside multiplication was used.

Comment: I have added f, copied from mathematica. I do not know what is the best way to present it on stackexchange though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Added verification of `Product`

f can be expressed in closed form:

```
f[m_, n_, t_] = Product[1 +
   Sum[(m + i)^k/t^(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity}],
  {i, 1, n}]
```

> (m - t)/(m + n - t)

Verifying the `Product` (proof by induction)

```
s[i_] = 1 + Sum[(m + i)^k/t^(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

> 1 - 1/(i + m - t)

```
f[m, 1, t] == s[1] &&
  f[m, n + 1, t] == f[m, n, t]*s[n + 1] //
 Simplify
```

> True

Your desired expansion is

```
Series[f[m, n, t], {t, Infinity, 4}] // Simplify
```

[image]

The coefficients are

```
SeriesCoefficient[f[m, n, t], {t, Infinity, k}]
```

[image]

Verifying the expansion

```
f[m, n, t] == 1 + Sum[n (m + n)^(k - 1)/t^k, {k, 1, Infinity}] // Simplify
```

> True

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Excuse me, I do not know how the closed form expression was derived. When I sum the infinity series, I got $$1 + \frac{1}{t-m-i}$$. How to show $$\Pi_{i=1}^n  1 + \frac{1}{t-m-i} = \frac{ m-t}{m+n-t} $$?

Comment: Evaluating `Product[1 + 1/(t - m - i), {i, 1, n}]` in Mma gives `(m-t)/(m+n-t)`

Comment: I mean the details of derivation, not how mathematica gives the answer...

Comment: Got it, just write the formula explicitly, $\Pi_{i=1}^n 1 + \frac{1}{t-m-i} = \frac{ t-m}{t-m-1} \frac{t-m-1}{t-m-2} \frac{t-m-2}{t-m-3} \cdots \frac{t-m-(n-1)}{t-m-n}$ and cancel the same terms on denominator and numeriator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your product is one that Mathematica doesn't know the closed form for, you could use my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156280/45431) from [Infinite product with O[x]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156259/45431) here:

```
Unprotect[Series];

Series[Product[a_, b_], pt_] := Exp[MapAt[Sum[#, b]&, Series[Log[a], pt], 3]]
Series[Inactive[Product][a_, b_], pt_] := Series[Unevaluated[Product[a, b]], pt]

Protect[Series];
```

Then:

```
f = Inactive[Product][1 + 1/t + (m + i)/t^2 + (m + i)^2/t^3, {i, 1, n}];

Simplify @ Series[f, {t, Infinity, 3}] //TeXForm
```

> $1+\frac{n}{t}+\frac{n (m+n)}{t^2}+\frac{n (m+n)^2}{t^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^4\right)$